# Light passing through two sets of double-slits in tandem

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference, wave-particle-duality

Has anyone ever set up a double double-slit experiment - one in which a second double-slit is inserted at one of the bright spots of the interference pattern produced by the first one? The intensity of the light which passes through the first slit and reaches the second screen will of course be much reduced. But my prediction is that all the photons will appear to exit the second double-slit at a subtended angle exactly the same as that between the first double-slit and the highlight on the first screen where the second double-slit was located. Furthermore a second interference pattern will not occur. Has this experiment been done, I can't find it mentioned anywhere on the web? And if so what was the outcome? If not, is my prediction justified by the Scrödinger wave equation or should there be a second much fainter interference pattern?

Comment: Your prediction is wrong. A second much fainter interference pattern will appear. But can you expand your question to explain why you think a second interference pattern won't appear? At the moment the possible answers to your question are just *yes* and *no*, which isn't very illuminating. If you explain why you think a second pattern won't appear we could address the errors in your reasoning.

Comment: Numerically solving the Schroedinger equation is fairly straightforward; if you're looking for a project then you could run a computer simulation to see exactly what happens.

Comment: The probability derived from the Scrödinger wave equation has been narrowed to the particular peak in the interference pattern.If it were measured here the wave function would have collapsed and a particular value  followed. But no measurement has been made. So now we can narrow down the probability as it passes through the second set of slits to what it would have been if it had been measured. Hence my prediction.If this isn't the case the photon would have been able to change its value in the Scrödinger wave equation without being measured. Isn't this a violation of the physics involved?